# Converting vector cells to polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile containing vector cells showing gradients of calcium pressure in soil. I want to convert the cell classifications into polygons in order to improve the visualization. 
I'm new to GIS in general and even more so QGIS and have tried different things, like converting into points and then buffers, but without any satisfactory results.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by vector cells, do you mean raster cells? In other words, do you want to convert raster to vector?

Comment: What is the image showing? The vector cells? Buffered points? A raster, maybe? Also, describe the visualization you are hoping to achieve and how it's different than the image you posted.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Convert a raster in polygons require at least the purpose of the process itself, I mean if you want to show 4 categories (as in your image) you need to reclassify raster before converting it.

Comment: I guess you want to convert vector grid cells into a polygon shapefile where each polygon has same Calcium Pressure value? Please clarify if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes Kuljeet or where each polygon represents an interval of pressure values.